Route53 DNS Resolution With Multiple Hosted Zone
I have the domain named abc.com and the hosted zone of this domain is on aws account A.
I have another AWS account which I have an ec2 instance with subdomains of abc.com like foo.abc.com
I have created a private hosted zone on the second aws account to resolve some of the domains via private IP
but the issue is that as mentioned earlier abc.com's actual hosted zone is on the first AWS account and if I try to run the dig command for a record created on the first hosted zone from the ec2 instance on the second AWS account it is not resolving.
The reason could be that the ec2 instance is only taking the second AWS account hosted zone.
My requirement is that the domain resolution should done on both hosted zone

In your AWS account A, you need to create an NS record for foo.abc.com thats equal to the name servers of your foo.abc.com hosted zone in account B. That is the "magic" that will make all of your foo.abc.com records resolve from the hosted zone in account B.

hi Patrick, there will be many subdomains generated so do I need to perform this while creating subdomains, Is there a single point forwarding possible?
